# Translating Drupal 8 Custom Route Paths with Parameters

Tags: routes, drupal-8, translate

I have the following route

```
my_module.order_details:
    path: '/account/orders/{orderId}'
```

Is there any way in Drupal 8 that I can translate this route path once?

For all the other routes I have been getting away with adding one url alias in the language I require a translation in. However, because this has the parameter {orderId} that doesn't appear to work, and I can't find a way to add a wild card into url aliases.(which would sort my problem, I think)

I know I could potentially create a translated url alias for each orderId but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Example of route translation with dynamic routes:

your_module.routing.yml

```
route_callbacks:
  - '\Drupal\your_module\DynamicRoutes\DynamicRoutes::routes'
```

your_module/src/DynamicRoutes/DynamicRoutes.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\your_module\DynamicRoutes;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;


/**
 * Listens to the dynamic trousers route events.
 */
class DynamicRoutes {

  public function routes(){
    $route_collection = new RouteCollection();


    $route_lang_en = new Route(
      // path
      '/example-lang-en',
      // defaults
      [
        // example controller
        '_controller' => '\Drupal\system\Controller\SystemController::systemAdminMenuBlockPage',
        '_title' => 'Your title en'
      ],
      // requirements:
      [
        '_permission' => 'access content',
      ]
    );
    $route_collection->add('example.language_en', $route_lang_en);

    $route_lang_fr = new Route(
      '/example-lang-fr',
      [
        '_controller' => '\Drupal\system\Controller\SystemController::systemAdminMenuBlockPage',
        '_title' => 'Your title fr'
      ],
      ['_permission' => 'access content']
    );
    $route_collection->add('example.language_fr', $route_lang_fr);

    return $route_collection;
  }
}
```

This function is equivalent for:

```
example.language_en:
  path: '/example-lang-en'
  defaults:
    _controller => '\Drupal\system\Controller\SystemController::systemAdminMenuBlockPage',
    _title => 'Your title en'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'

example.language_fr:
  path: '/example-lang-fr'
  defaults:
    _controller => '\Drupal\system\Controller\SystemController::systemAdminMenuBlockPage',
    _title => 'Your title fr'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

The code aboce is for explanation only. However I suggest that routes are build whit some custom reusable method that iterate trough all languages, with custom translation for `path` and `_title`, while `_controller`, `'_permission'` and any other untranslatable data is reused in each route translation.

For debugging routes [drupal console](https://drupalconsole.com/) is very useful

`drupal dr` (list all routes)

`drupal dr example.language_en` (get en example route parameters)

`drupal dr example.language_fr` (get fr example route parameters)